# Async iterate over collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So my goal is to have a command that shows all the bots commands and the attached user permissions. I have the function to fetch the list of commands

```js
var commands = await interaction.guild.commands.fetch()
    .catch(error => {
        interaction.reply({content: 'Unknown Error', ephemeral: true})
    })
```

And this all works fine, i get a nice collection of my commands, my question is, (which i have been unable to solve for 2 hours). Is how can i iterate over this collection and get the perms for each command, i know how to get the perms for a single command with this

```js
var perms = await interaction.guild.commands.permissions.fetch({command: command.id})
```

but how can i get a JSON list with all the perms for each command that also can accommodate for perms being undefined (as some commands dont have attached perms)

The issue i have been having is that a function to do so like this

```js
await commands.each(async (command) => {
    await interaction.guild.commands.permissions.fetch({command: command.id})
        .then(perms => {
            console.log(`**${command.name}** \`${command.id}\``)
            fields.push({title: command.id, value: perms})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Triggered if command has no perms
            fields.push({title: command.id, value: 'None'})
        })
})
```

with this the code afterwards that uses fields continues before the fields is filled meaning my message is always empty. How can i make the following code wait for this loop to have fully finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like this:

```
await Promise.all(commands.map(async (command) => {
    try {
        const perms = await interaction.guild.commands.permissions.fetch({command: command.id})
        console.log(`**${command.name}** \`${command.id}\``)
        fields.push({title: command.id, value: perms})
    }
    catch(e) {
        //Triggered if command has no perms
        fields.push({title: command.id, value: 'None'})
    }
}))

// At this point the fields array is full (order not guaranteed however)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I wouldn't mix up `await` with `.then()`.

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the `Discord.Collection` of `ApplicationCommand`s into an array and then simply use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Also note that [`ApplicationCommand`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommand) has `.permissions` property, so you can take advantage of that.

Straightforward solution (no callbacks):

```js
const fields = [];
const commands = await interaction.guild.commands.fetch();

for (const command of Array.from(commands.values())) {
    try {
        const permissions = await command.permissions.fetch();
        fields.push({title: command.id, value: permissions});
    } catch {
        fields.push({title: command.id, value: "None"});
    }
}
```

After that the `fields` array will look something like this (converted into a JSON for visualization):

```json
[
  {
    "title": "878405785552551936", 
    "value": "None"
  },
  {
    "title": "878405793769193473", 
    "value": "None"
  },
  {
    "title": "878405796118003714", 
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "878405800618491907",
        "permission": true,        
        "type": "USER"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^13.1.0`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [for await...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

The for await...of statement creates a loop iterating over async iterable objects as well as on sync iterables, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined async/sync iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object. This statement can only be used inside an async function.